# SAS find text (partial) and delete the observation

Tags: sas

Data looks like this:

```
data test;
input v1 $ v2 v3;
datalines;
AB 4 5
AB 0 4
A 4 .
A 1 0
;;;;
run;
```

V2 is the test result for A and V3 is a test result for B.

If V1 does not contain the letter "B" and it has a number 0, it should be replaced by the number zero.

Logic would be something like this:

```
if V1 does not contain A AND V2 = 0 then replace V2 = .
if V1 does not contain B AND V3 = 0 then replace V3 = .
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Edited some for clarity; please update your question to be more clear between the initial logic statement and the second pair which are not identical.

Comment: Thank you Joe. your answer helped me a lot. I used index to make another variable that shows whether the character is present. Then I assigned 'missing' to the ones that does not contain the character and dropped the new variable that I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FIND or INDEX (both work similarly, with slightly different options).  I don't completely understand your logic as it's inconsistent, but going with your example logic:

```
if find(v1,"A") = 0 and v2=0 then call missing(v2); *or then v2=. or then v2=whatever;
```

Similar for B and V3.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a sql step using `CASE` and `LIKE`

eg

```
proc sql noprint;

  create table test1 as
  select V1, case
                 when V1 NOT LIKE '%A%' and V2 = 0 then .
                 else V2
             end as V2,
             case
                 when V1 NOT LIKE '%B%' and V3 = 0 then .
                 else V3
             end as V3
   from test
   ;
quit;
```